# How to return a list of objects as XML in Spring boot rest API

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, web-services, jackson

I'm writing a Java webservice which will return the list of Products in the below XML format.

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    
    <Products>
    <Product>
        <Name>Notepad++ 6</Name>
        <PatchUid>00038b09-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</PatchUid>
        <RegID>0</RegID>
    </Product>
    <Product>
        <Name>UltraVNC 1.2.4.0 x86</Name>   
        <PatchUid>00035767-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</PatchUid>
        <RegID>0</RegID>
    </Product>
    <Product>
        <Name>FileZilla 3</Name>    
        <PatchUid>00038c69-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</PatchUid>
        <RegID>1033</RegID>
    </Product>
    </Products>
```

I'm fetching the Name, PatchUid, RegId tags from the jdbc/hibernate connection using a class based projection shown below.

```
public class ProductView implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @JsonProperty("Name")
    String name;
    @JsonProperty("PatchUid")
    String patchuid;
    @JsonProperty("RegId")
    String language;

    public ProductView() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public ProductView(String name, String patchuid, String language) {
        this.name = name;
        this.patchuid = patchuid;
        this.language = language;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPatchuid() {
        return patchuid;
    }

    public void setPatchuid(String patchuid) {
        this.patchuid = patchuid;
    }

    public String getLanguage() {
        return language;
    }

    public void setLanguage(String language) {
        this.language = language;
    }

}
```

Now, to return the XML response, I am using the below DTO class and rest controller method

```
    public class Products implements Serializable {
        
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 3639898896768313168L;
        
        
        private List<ProductView> products;
    
        public Products() {
            super();
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }
    
        public Products(List<ProductView> products) {
            this.products = products;
        }
    
        public List<ProductView> getProduct() {
            return products;
        }
    
        public void setProduct(List<ProductView> products) {
    
            this.products = products;
        }
    
    }
    
    
    @GetMapping("/patchMetadata")
    public Products getProductMetadata(@RequestParam(required=false) Boolean filtered) {
            
            logger.info("getProductMetadata called");
    
            List<ProductView> prodViews = null;
            
            if(filtered == null || filtered == false)
            {
                prodViews = prodMgmtService.findAllPatches();
            }
            else if (filtered == true) {
                prodViews = prodMgmtService.findFilteredPatches();
            } 
    
            Products products = new Products();
            products.setProduct(prodViews);
    
            return products;
    }
```

But the returned XML format is shown below. Please note the extra product tag that needs to be removed.

```
    <Products>
        <product>
            <product>
                <Name>FileZilla 3</Name>
                <PatchUid>0003931b-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</PatchUid>
                <RegId>0</RegId>
            </product>
            <product>
                <Name>Notepad++ 6</Name>
                <PatchUid>00038b09-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</PatchUid>
                <RegId>0</RegId>
            </product>
            <product>
                <Name>UltraVNC 1.2.4.0 x86</Name>
                <PatchUid>00035767-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</PatchUid>
                <RegId>0</RegId>
            </product>
        </product>
    </Products>
```

Please let me know for any suggestions to correct the returned XML format from the webservice.

Comment: May be you can use response object to write the list explicitly. Pass the response object to this method use response stream and write back the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the Products DTO class as below by using the @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false) worked.

public class Products implements Serializable {

```
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3639898896768313168L;
    
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    @JsonProperty("Product")
    private List<ProductView> product;

    public Products() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public Products(List<ProductView> products) {
        this.product = products;
    }

    public List<ProductView> getProduct() {
        return product;
    }

    public void setProduct(List<ProductView> products) {

        this.product = products;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning `Products` from your service, return `List<ProductView>`:

```
@GetMapping("/patchMetadata")
public List<ProductView> getProductMetadata(@RequestParam(required=false) Boolean filtered) {
    List<ProductView> prodViews = null;
    if(filtered == null || filtered == false) {
        prodViews = prodMgmtService.findAllPatches();
    } else if (filtered == true) {
        prodViews = prodMgmtService.findFilteredPatches();
    } 

    return prodViews;
}
```

Comment: I have already tried that, and I'm seeing weird labels like <list> and <item> in the response as show below.

Comment: <List>
    <item>
        <Name>FileZilla 3</Name>
        <PatchUid>0003931b-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</PatchUid>
        <RegId>0</RegId>
    </item>
    <item>
        <Name>Notepad++ 6</Name>
        <PatchUid>00038b09-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</PatchUid>
        <RegId>0</RegId>
    </item>
    <item>
        <Name>UltraVNC 1.2.4.0 x86</Name>
        <PatchUid>00035767-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</PatchUid>
        <RegId>0</RegId>
    </item>
</List>